# Rabbitmq user permissions in Windows

Tags: java, windows, openssl, rabbitmq

What should I do to make sure that my rabbitmq user has permission  to run : C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe .
In fact i want to use SSL protocole with Rabbitmq but the node crashes. Here's the sslLogfile :

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 4-May-2016::18:33:16 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: rabbit_mgmt_external_stats:init/1
    pid: <0.233.0>
    registered_name: rabbit_mgmt_external_stats
    exception exit: {eacces,
                        [{erlang,open_port,
                             [{spawn,
                                  "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c handle.exe /accepteula -s -p 2052 2> nul"},
                              [stream,in,eof,hide]],
                             []},
                         {os,cmd,1,[{file,"os.erl"},{line,204}]},
                         {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,get_used_fd,1,[]},
                         {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,'-infos/2-lc$^0/1-0-',2,
                             []},
                         {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,'-infos/2-lc$^0/1-0-',2,
                             []},
                         {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,emit_update,1,[]},
                         {rabbit_mgmt_external_stats,handle_info,2,[]},
                         {gen_server,handle_msg,5,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,599}]}]}
      in function  gen_server:terminate/6 (gen_server.erl, line 746)
    ancestors: [rabbit_mgmt_agent_sup,<0.231.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.232.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 4185
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 77435063
  neighbours:
```

Here's my rabbitmq.config file :

```
[
   {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.2']}]},
   {
     rabbit, 
      [
          {ssl_listeners, [5676]},
  {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"D:/Profiles/user/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/testca/cacert.pem"},
                         {certfile,  "D:/Profiles/user/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/server/cert.pem"},
                         {keyfile,   "D:/Profiles/user/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/server/key.pem"},
                         {versions, ['tlsv1.2']},
          {verify,verify_peer},
                         {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}
 ]},    
       {loopback_users, []}
      ]
   }
].
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eacces` is an Erlang file error:

> eacces:
>       Missing permission for reading the file, or for searching one of the parent directories.

Set the right permissions.

Stop the RabbitMQ service and try to use `rabbitmq-server.bat` and execute it as administrator.

Then check the logs

Comment: yes that helped a lot solving my problem, indeed the OpenSSL files were in some folders that the service couldn't acces, thanks